# Racemization of hydrocarbon in presence of AlCl3

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, stereochemistry

Our textbook mentioned that the compound in the diagram racemizes in presence of $\ce{AlCl3}$, but it didn't explain anything.  [image: image for compound]

Any help regarding the mechanism of the reaction would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you'll get better results if you specifically ask the question you have, not just stating a situation you don't understand.

Comment: @StianYttervik I just want to know how the reaction proceeds. Was it that difficult to decipher from the post ?

Comment: @HelloWorld1729 Please cite your textbook, use proper compound name ((butan‐2‐yl)benzene), mention conditions and your thoughts on mechanism. Also, please refrain from using MathJax in titles and feel free  to check out [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your posts better with MathJax and Markdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plausible reaction leading to your product is the following reaction:

[image]

i.e., a mixture of (*R*) and (*S*)-configurated product is formed.  In the presence of $\ce{AlCl3}$, the alkylhalogenide becomes something *like* a carba cation, where you potentially loose stereogenic information (-> racemic mixture). In the work-up, the addition of water destroys [quenches] $\ce{AlCl3}$, thus the forward and backward reaction no longer is catalyzed, and eventually, it is possible to separate the two isomers.

*However*, if you mix one of the two *pure* isomers with $\ce{AlCl3}$ (or an other Lewis acid, e.g., $\ce{FeCl3}$ and heat the mixture, you will again generate a mixture of alkylated benzene.  (I intentionally use *mixture* here; because the installation of an alkyl group increases benzene's character as a Lewis base [$\pi$ bonds!], eventually, you might end up with more than one alkyl group installed, too.)

The reversible character of the [Friedel-Crafts alkylation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedel%E2%80%93Crafts_reaction) may be used to your advantage, though to block e.g., the *p*-position relative to an already installed substitutent directing in (*ortho*) and (*para*)-position, especially with a *tert*-butyl group.